# Do almost all ext4 filesystems have 4KiB blocks?

Tags: ext4, block-device

Many sources, such as https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man8/mkfs.ext4.8.html read:

> ...block-size is heuristically determined by the filesystem size...

What is this heuristic?

In which source file can the calculation be found?

Do all modern HDDs/SSDs (i.e. over 100 GB) cause 4KiB blocks by default with this heuristic?

Comment: Link may be 10 years old, but it was design of larger/newer drives. https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-4kb-sector-disks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation seems to be quite simple: if the block size is not selected by user it defaults to page size (so 4096) or logical sector size of the device if it's bigger than page size (there are few more exceptions, but this should cover most of the cases).

The `e2fsprogs` source is available [here](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs) and the code that sets blocksize in `mke2fs` is [here](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/master/misc/mke2fs.c#L2136).